# Why should I need libprofiler.so.0

Tags: c++, compilation, dynamic-library, tcmalloc

I am using google prof tools, and link my app with -lprofiler, but when I run this program:
error while loading shared libraries: libprofiler.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

on the contrary, I link with -ltcmalloc then I do not need a tcmalloc.so at runtime.

I have already link the static lib for profiler, why should I need it at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static library just contains stubs for calling actual functions from the shared object dynamically. So you will need the .so as well. The static library makes your life easier, so that you don't have to write `GetProcAddress()` or whatever it is on your system.